# Positioning Radiobuttons in LabelFrame

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, alignment, calculation

how can i align the buttons symetrically, so that they sit perfectly in the frame and have all the same distance to the sides and their neighbors

my approach was this one here, but it does not bring the right result...

```
class MyApproach():

    def __init__(self):
        self.radiobutton_name_list = {"radio1": "This_is_text",
                                  "radio2": "This_is_mid_text",
                                  "radio3": "This_is_loooooooong_text"}
        self.create_root()
        self.create_label_frame()
        self.create_radiobuttons()
        self.mainloop()

    def create_root(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("740x120")
        self.root.title("test")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)

    def create_label_frame(self):
        self.new_labelframe = LabelFrame(self.root, text='My Frame', relief=GROOVE, bd=2)
        self.new_labelframe.place(width=720, height=80, x=10, y=10)

    def create_radiobuttons(self):
        self.radiobutton_xposition = 10
        for radiobuttons in self.radiobutton_name_list:
            if not len(self.radiobutton_name_list) <= 4: break
            Radiobutton(self.new_labelframe, text=self.radiobutton_name_list[radiobuttons]).place(
                        x=self.radiobutton_xposition, y=10)
            self.radiobutton_xposition += len(self.radiobutton_name_list[radiobuttons])

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


app = MyApproach()
```

I do not know how to do the calculation, but "self.radiobutton_xposition + = len (self.radiobutton_name_list [radiobuttons])" is not correct and (* =) I guess that's the wrong approach

thank you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, using place as your geometry manager gives you more problems than it solves. Why don't you use pack?

```
from tkinter import *

class MyApproach():

    def __init__(self):
        self.radiobutton_name_list = {"radio1": "This_is_text",
                                  "radio2": "This_is_mid_text",
                                  "radio3": "This_is_loooooooong_text"}
        self.create_root()
        self.create_label_frame()
        self.create_radiobuttons()
        self.mainloop()

    def create_root(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("740x120")
        self.root.title("test")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)

    def create_label_frame(self):
        self.new_labelframe = LabelFrame(self.root, text='My Frame', relief=GROOVE, bd=2)
        self.new_labelframe.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH, padx=10, pady=10)

    def create_radiobuttons(self):
        self.v = StringVar()
        self.v.set(' ')
        for radiobuttons in self.radiobutton_name_list:
            r = Radiobutton(self.new_labelframe, text=self.radiobutton_name_list[radiobuttons], variable=self.v, value=radiobuttons)
            r.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, expand=1, fill=X)

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


app = MyApproach()
```

Comment: My solutions uses weights on each column but I like the use you have with pack.

Comment: I dont think you need `r = Radiobuttons` as you wont be able to use that variable to edit the buttons later. Probably cleaner to remove `r =` and place pack at the end of the button creation line.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: I disagree. Moving `pack` to a separate line makes the code much easier to read than if it was tacked on at the end.

Comment: @BryanOakley Well I guess for me its more about reducing the code where you can. I know that `r` cant be used after the buttons are made here so it seams to me to be an extra step you do not need to do.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: but `r` _is_ used -- it's used in order to enable calling `pack`. Code is read much more than it is written, so unless performance is absolutely critical (which it almost never is in GUI initialization), optimize for readability

Comment: @BryanOakley fair enough. When I write for loops like this that generate buttons I normally put everything in a list or use the grid manager on the same line as the button creations as a variable name is useless after the loop is complete. I should probably practice better readability.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Yeah I think the message of both our answers is the same: don't use place in situations where you can get grid or pack to do what you want. As for the pack on the separate line, I kinda lose the overview when I pack widgets on the same line they're created. When possible I even like to group all pack calls per parent. This gives me a better overview of how the widgets are placed, especially since the order in which you pack widgets makes a difference.

Comment: @fhdrsdg I guess my answer servers to illustrate how grid wold do the job and yours shows how pack will do the job. It is worth noting that the order you assign pack() matters but the order for grid does not.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

The quickest solutions I can think of is to provide weights to each column and then place you buttons there. Place has its moments but for the most part you can solve placement issues with `pack()` or `grid()`.

Here we will use grid and generate the column numbers with a range.

Try the below:

```
from tkinter import *

class MyApproach():

    def __init__(self):
        # updated the data here so it would be easier to run a loop over it.
        self.radiobutton_name_list = {0: ["radio1", "This_is_text"],
                                  1: ["radio2", "This_is_mid_text"],
                                  2: ["radio3", "This_is_loooooooong_text"]}

        self.create_root()
        self.create_label_frame()
        self.create_radiobuttons()
        self.mainloop()

    def create_root(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("740x120")
        self.root.title("test")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)

    def create_label_frame(self):
        self.new_labelframe = LabelFrame(self.root, text='My Frame', relief=GROOVE, bd=2)
        self.new_labelframe.place(width=720, height=80, x=10, y=10)

    def create_radiobuttons(self):
        # using len and range to get the key of the radio button list.
        # this same key number can be used as the column as well.
        for i in range(len(self.radiobutton_name_list)):
            self.new_labelframe.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
            Radiobutton(self.new_labelframe, text=self.radiobutton_name_list[i][1]).grid(row=0, column=i, sticky="nsew")

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


app = MyApproach()
```